# Use .resx with AngularJs translation

Tags: .net, angularjs, globalization, resx, angular-translate

What's the best approach to transforming `.resx` files into the necessary JS format for `angular-translate` (AngularJS)?
We use `grunt` as a build tool, but couldn't find any taks that would do this out of the box.
And we use `.Net` on the server side so try to keep our translation strings in `.resx`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not out of the box but have you considered using a console application to generate a JS file with all your translations as a PreBuildTask?

The example here could form a basis for writing this application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically#enumerate-resources.

However, it seems the if you have a server side application in C# it might be worth looking to avoid the overhead of downloading all your text in all supported languages but rather downloading just the translation for the selected country?